# Determine most important features in diagnostic data

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, logistic-regression, machine-learning-model

I have a dataset of device diagnostics. I have two tables: one relating each device to failures code. Two devices can share a failure code for example a common chip malfunction. The second table links the device to signs of failure for example overheating. Each sign has a severity score and devices can have overlapping signs. For instance:

```
Device_code,Failure_code
X001,8989
X001,8650
X001,8490
X002,8989
X002,8650
X002,3433
....

Device_code | signs | severity
8989, s1234, 1
8989, s2345, 4
8989, s4567, 2
8650, s1234, 4
8650, s9999, 1
...
```

How can I find the most important `signs` for each `Failure_code`?

I thought about merging the tables, converting each `sign` to a binary column, where 1 and 0 mean the failure has the feature or not, resp. Then running a logistic regression to predict `failure_code` and sort by coefficients. However, in this method I cannot use the `severity` feature. What is a good method to approach this problem?

Thanks!